# how to logout an user when date is changed

Tags: android, date, alarmmanager

I'm developing an app where user need to be logged out when date is changed. As i'm using **alarm manager** to log out the user, but i'm unable to do it. Is their is any chance to logout the user using date.

**The code is below**

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();

/* setting time */
timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
timeOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this action

```
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
    /**eg
      this.sysForbidenReceiver.checkTime(this);
      this.registerReceiver(this.sysForbidenReceiver, filter);
    **/
```

Comment: can u explain it briefly

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK

Answer (score 0):

use this code on your firs Activity onCreateMethod

```
var currentDate = LocalDateEx.getNow().toString()
        Log.d("experiment",currentDate)

        var previousDate = Utility.getEDate(this)
        Log.d("dshf",previousDate)
        if (currentDate != previousDate){

            Utility.setEDate(this,currentDate)
            DBManager.deleteAllPlants(this)
            DBManager.deleteAllStates(this)
            DBManager.deleteAllBanks(this)
            DBManager.deleteAllDesignations(this)

            val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        else{
            Utility.setEDate(this,currentDate)
        }
```

use this to store your date in shared preference

```
fun setEDate(context: Context, eDate: String) {
            context.getSharedPreferences("", 0).edit().putString(DATE, eDate).apply()
        }
```

use this code to get date from shared preference

```
fun getEDate(context: Context): String? {
            return context.getSharedPreferences("", 0).getString(DATE, priviousDateDefault)
        }
```